# Risks and rewards of using /dev/autofs_nowait on OS X

Tags: asynchronous, core-foundation, bsd, vfs, xnu

Throughout the [CoreFoundation framework source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF), POSIX filesystem API calls (e.g. `open()`, `stat()`, *et al…*) are [wrapped in an idiom](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF/blob/3cc41a76b1491f50813e28a4ec09954ffa359e6f/CFFileUtilities.c#L65-L71) wherein a descriptor on `/dev/autofs_nowait` is acquired – with `open(…, 0)` – before the POSIX calls are made; afterwards the descriptor is `close()`’d before the scope exits.

- What is the benefit of doing this? What are the risks?
- Does acquiring the `/dev/autofs_nowait` descriptor have any affect on, or is it effected by, flags to any thusly-wrapped `open()` calls (like e.g. `O_NONBLOCK`)?
- `/dev` on my machine, running OS X 10.10.5 has other “autofs” entries:

  > [image: dev directory listing]

  … none of which have `man` pages available. If these file-like devices might offer benefits in this vein I would be interested to hear about their use as well, as it may pertain.

---

Addendum: I could not find much on this subject; a [Google Plus post from 2011](https://plus.google.com/106726538507001003804/posts/a83FonJPfYg) claims that:

> [t]his file is a special device that's monitored by the autofs
>   filesystem implementation in the kernel. When opened, the autofs
>   filesystem will not block that process on any I/O operations on an
>   autofs file system.

I am not quite sure what that means (they were specifically talking about how `launchd` works, FWIW) but I was curious about this myself, so I wrote [a quick  context-manager-y RAII struct](https://github.com/fish2000/libimread/blob/master/include/libimread/ext/filesystem/nowait.h) to [try it out](https://github.com/fish2000/libimread/blob/7a8b832a690406ac5a1c3eaca00cef71f0a2b4fe/src/ext/filesystem/path.cpp#L862-L896) – untargeted profiling shows  tests with POSIX calls completing faster but within general hashmarks; I’ll investigate this tactic with a finer-toothed comb after I get more background on how it all works.

Comment: If this works on a per-process basis, this may cause undesirable behavior in other threads that *don't* want the inhibition.

Comment: @o11c Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These devices allowed the implementor(s) to avoid to define a new `syscall` or `ioctl` for the functionality, and maybe it was implemented that way because it was simpler, requires updating less code, and does not change the VFS API, which may have been the concerns at the time.

When you open `/dev/autofs_nowait` and traverse a path, you trigger auto-mounts, but don't wait for them to finish (otherwise your process blocks until the filesystem is mounted or after the operation times out), so you may receive a `ENOENT` when opening a file even if everything goes fine.

OTOH, `/dev/autofs_notrigger` makes the process not even trigger the auto-mounting.

That is all those devices do. The thing is that, in Darwin's implementation, `open` may block when traversing the filesystem even with `O_NONBLOCK` or `O_NDELAY`.

You can follow the flow from the vfs, from the `open` operation of a `vnode`:

- `vn_open` -> [`vn_open_auth`](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/vfs/vfs_vnops.c#L364) ->
- [`namei`](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/vfs/vfs_lookup.c#L166) -> [`lookup`](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/vfs/vfs_lookup.c#L925) -> ...

Down that path there's no handling of the (non)blocking behavior.

Comment: OK so if I understand correctly, the implementor(s) created both `/dev/autofs_nowait` and `/dev/autofs_notrigger` to essentially avoid having to add a new flag to e.g. `fcntl()` specifying `autofs` behavior?… Would you call that a correctly dumbed-down synopsis?

Comment: Not exactly, `fcntl` operates on an specific (already open) fd, while `autofs_nowait` affects every operation. Why it was implemented that way? maybe because it was simpler, requires updating less code, and does not change the VFS API, which may have been the concerns at the time.

Comment: For some applications (interactive ones specially) it may make sense to block, except to the auto-mounter, and that's probably why it's used in CF.

Comment: Thank you, @IsmaelLuceno, for amending the answer – this is all excellent information you have provided I must say. Is there any chance you could top it off with a solid citation link or two, where one could go for further reading on `autofs` and these `/dev` entries? That would truly take the cake, if I can say so.

Comment: Also, @IsmaelLuceno – in your view, would it appropriate to retag this question  under `autofs`?

Comment: There's no much information about it but the code... the other interesting part is in the autofs kext...

Comment: It would be interesting to investigate the history behind it.

Comment: @fish2000 and yes, I find appropriate to re-tag it, though I can't create the tag, but I added xnu and vfs and removed the others since it seems less relevant. I'm not entirely sure if the bsd tag would apply, but I guess so, and the c tag could be removed...

Comment: And I did it, IMO the c tag doesn't apply because we're discussing behavior, so code is secondary...

Comment: Hey @IsmaelLuceno – I know this isn’t the most currently active question on SO but your example links into the VFS source code in the Darwin XNU repo have gone dead; no biggie really but if you should find yourself able to spare a moment enough to patch those up, I’d much appreciate it. Yes!

Comment: @fish2000 Fixed.